# How can I create Custom Connector for Javascript for my Custom State in Vaadin 7.4.6

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

I found that we can create our custom connectors for our custom components in the vaadin. But I need to have a explicit/custom Connector for my Javascript. I noticed Vaadin create a implicit Javascript connector for itself at runtime.

How do I create a connector for my Javascript Component and bind it with Javascript component.